# Open Shift remote Git repository reset or delete

Tags: git, openshift

I am testing and triying to use openshift for first time ever,
and i did not realize the size limitation in space included git repository too.

Now my remote git repository is full, and i cannot do nothing with it.
Is there a way to remotely purge, or reset my git repository and start from scracth without having to delete the application?

Comment: Are you able to ssh to your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the code without the history (the current source), you can do the following.

- Make a backup of the current git repo anywhere in case you need it someday.
- Delete the `.git` folder on your OpenShift
- Start a new repository with the `git init` and now work on a new repository.

Keep in mind that you have the old one as backup in case you need it someday.